# How do I target an ActiveX Label inlineshape to change the backcolor and hide the text in the label

Tags: vba, ms-word

I just found this code from a website which works on an ActiveX textbox control. I would like it to work on a label ActiveX control where when I submit the command button control two things happen in the label: The label changes from red to white And .caption = "". (my goal is to have the label hide).

The code I'm trying works with a textbox control, but not a label because I think they're different data types? (I get a mismatch error).  Can you help - and thanks ahead?

Here is what I've tried, but get the error:

```
    Dim ils As Word.InlineShape
Dim olef As Word.OLEFormat
Dim tb As MSForms.Label
Set ils = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1)
Set olef = ils.OLEFormat
Set tb = olef.Object
tb = lbl_test
lbl_test.Caption = ""
lbl_test.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get a Type Mismatch error in the "Set ils" line if the InlineShape referenced by InlineShapes(1) is *not* an MSForms.Label. So perhaps your code is working with the wrong shape. If InlineShapes(1) *is* an MSForms.Label, this should work:

```
Dim ils As Word.InlineShape
Dim olef As Word.OLEFormat
Dim tb As MSForms.Label
Set ils = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1)
Set olef = ils.OLEFormat
Set tb = olef.Object
tb.Caption = ""
tb.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
```

This line

```
tb = lbl_test
```

may be doing something rather different than what you think. Putting

lbl_test.Caption = ""

after it suggests that you are trying to create a reference to the MSForms.Label object, but I would guess that lbl_test is a string variable (we can't see from the snippet you provide). If so, trying to set

```
lbl_test.Caption
```

would also cause an error.

What

```
tb = lbl_test
```

actually does is to assign the value of lbl_test to the "default member" of the tb object. For an MSForms.Label object, the default member is .Caption, (you can look it up in the VB Editor's Object Viewer) so in fact that line should set the caption of the label. But it's better practice not to rely on default members and to spell it out as

```
tb.Caption = lbl_test
```

There are a couple of ways you can access ActiveX controls in the document surface. There's this one, but you may also be able to access the control directly from ThisDocument if you happen to know its name, via e.g. ThisDocument.Label1. Then you don't really need to know the control's type.

But otherwise you have to access the InlineShape or Shape as you are doing. Because different ActiveX controls do have different members (e.g. a label has a caption but a TextBox does not) you might be better off checking the object type before working with it, perhaps like this...

```
    Dim ils As Word.InlineShape
    Set ils = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1)
    If Not (ils.OLEFormat Is Nothing) Then
      With ils.OLEFormat
        Select Case .ClassType
        Case "Forms.Label.1"
          ' You don't even need to assign to an object variable
          With .Object
            .Caption = ""
            .BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
          End With
        Case "Forms.TextBox.1"
          ' do the appropriate thing
        Case "Forms.CheckBox.1"
          ' do the appropriate thing
        Case Else
          ' e.g. it might not be an ActiveX control
          ' perhaps do nothing
      End Select
    End With
  End If
```

Comment: "ThisDocument" - was just what I needed to accomplish what I needed - thanks again, it's working!